# PHP - Using cURL to get a cookie from a redirecting URL but getting no response

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I have a cURL command using which I get authenticated to a website and it gives a cookie in response, then subsequently using this cookie I can make REST API calls to this service

Here is the working cURL command:

```
curl -v -l -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Referrer:https://mywebsiteurl.com?ticket=unique_ticket_id" -d "_charset_=UTF-8&errorMessage=User+name+and+password+do+not+match&resource=%2F&username=username%40domain.com&password=XXXXXX&nextpage=welcomeCM.jsp&viewInfo=&ticket=unique_ticket_id"  -X  POST https://mywebsiteurl.com/index.jsp
```

In the above command ticket parameter contains a unique ticket id that is passed along with the website url

Now, I'm trying to accomplish the same using cURL PHP, here is the PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mywebsiteurl.com/index.jsp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "_charset_=UTF-8&errorMessage=User+name+and+password+do+not+match&resource=%2F&username=username%40domain.com&password=XXXXXX&nextpage=welcomeCM.jsp&viewInfo=&ticket=unique_ticket_id");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Referrer: https://mywebsiteurl.com?ticket=unique_ticket_id'
        );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

echo $result;

curl_close ($ch);
```

Here `echo $result` shows nothing

I then tried `var_dump($result);` and it gives this output: `string(0) ""` which means nothing is getting returned in `$response`

After this I tried `curl_getinfo` and added the following code:

```
echo "<pre>";
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
echo "</pre>";
```

And this gave me the following array:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://mywebsiteurl.com/index.jsp
    [content_type] => text/html;charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 302
    [header_size] => 1306
    [request_size] => 619
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.540687
    [namelookup_time] => 0.028262
    [connect_time] => 0.171774
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.462507
    [size_upload] => 280
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 181
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 280
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.54066
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => https://mywebsiteurl.com/welcomeCM.jsp?username=username@domain.com&locale=en_US
    [primary_ip] => YY.YYY.YYY.YY
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => XX.XX.XXX.XX
    [local_port] => 47692
)
```

Now my goal is to get the cookie in `$result`, but it is empty & nothing is getting returned into it

Is it that something is missing in the cURL command equivalent PHP code?

Can someone please help me out & point me in the direction to retrieve the cookie

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

I added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` to the request to have it follow the 302 redirect after successful login

But this time after the execution of cURL, `echo $result` is redirecting my current local webpage to `/Dashboard?viewInfo=` which obviously does not exist

Also this time `var_dump($result);` is resulting in: `string(1462) " "`

And `curl_getinfo($ch)` this time is giving the following array:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://mywebsiteurl.com/welcomeCM.jsp?username=username@domain.com&locale=en_US
    [content_type] => text/html;charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 1821
    [request_size] => 956
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 1
    [total_time] => 1.746911
    [namelookup_time] => 1.5E-5
    [connect_time] => 1.5E-5
    [pretransfer_time] => 6.2E-5
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 1462
    [speed_download] => 836
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 1462
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.146587
    [redirect_time] => 1.6003
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => YY.YYY.YYY.YY
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => YY.YY.YYY.YY
    [local_port] => 47705
)
```

Still can't get the required cookie here,
Please help!

Comment: One note which probably won't fix your problem but is worth knowing: "Referrer" is misspelled, it should be "Referer" (yes, that's the incorrect English spelling, but that's just how it is in HTTP).

Comment: You need to add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` to the request to have it follow the 302 redirect after successful login.

Comment: @HaydenSchiff
Yep you're right, indeed it is a misspell, but this is how it is in HTTP :)

Comment: @natheriel Before posting my question I tried the answer given on the link you shared but it didn't work for me as my URL is redirecting upon execution, I changed the question headline to emphasis on same

Comment: @dreamcoder007 Well, just to be sure. Your primary goal is to use curl, to login/authenticate yourself at some site + store the cookie. Afterwards you want to use the cookie to stay authenticated?

Comment: @natheriel Yep, using curl I want to authenticate myself to a site & then take the cookie value to make REST API calls to this service

Comment: @drew010 Thanks for your response, I added FOLLOWLOCATION and updated my question above, still not getting the cookie that I need

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use curls given functionality you can try using CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR / CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, to store and get your cookie. This if file based. 
In this case, curl will then write any Cookie related Information in a file.

You can define where this file will be located.

By using CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR , you will tell curl that it shall capture the cookie data.

```
// create cookie file
$cookie = __DIR__ . "/where/you/want/to/store/your/cookie/mycookie.txt";
fopen($cookie, "w");
// you may want to use some random identicator in your cookie file
// to make sure it does not get overwritten by some action

// prepare login
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mywebsiteurl.com/index.jsp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// tell curl to follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURlOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=usernam&password=XXXXXX");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// set a jar, to store your cookie
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
$headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Referrer: https://mywebsiteurl.com?ticket=unique_ticket_id'
        );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// do login
$loginResult = curl_exec($ch);

// check if your login has worked according to the given result by any method you want
if (preg_match("/Welcome/", $loginResult)) {
    // simple regex for demonstration purpose
}

// now you could load your cookie out of the file, or just use the file for future requests
```

If your login has worked, you will have all information stored in your cookie file.

Now you can use that cookie again with the curlopt CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE for future requests.

```
// do other request, with your cookie
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://mywebsiteurl.com/api/rest.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "your new post data");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
// set a jar to update your cookie if needed
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
// give curl the location of your cookie file, so it can send it
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!

I tried CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR as suggested by you.
But when I run the .php page with this code - instead of logging me in, it shows the login page of https://mywebsiteurl.com/index.jsp, now it seems the code scraped the login page from the website and then displayed it.

Still not able to get the needed cookie, can you please help